# Why can I see information travelling through HTTPS with Fiddler?

Tags: https, fiddler

I was trying to make a website that require the user to log in to do something, but I want to know the advantage and disadvantage from HTTP and HTTPS first.

I was using a program called Fiddler that allowed you to logs all HTTP(s) traffic between your computer and the Internet

if I try to log in with the program on, I could see the username and the password that I used to log in to the website, even if it's HTTP or HTTPS using fiddler

so what's the use of HTTPS compared with HTTP?

This is what I am thinking.

The browser is supposed to enscrypt the password using the server's public key right? Then the server will descript it with the private key.

But fiddler doesn't know the server's private key. So how can it sees the plain password?

Am I wrong?

Comment: One is secure and other is not.. [btw](https://www.google.com/search?q=http+vs+https&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)

Comment: FWIW, this isn't really a duplicate, it's just a poorly-formed question. The question is: "How is HTTPS secure, if Fiddler can see its traffic."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTTPS communication is sent over an encrypted channel, while HTTP is sent in plain-text. Most importantly his means that a 3rd party can't read information sent between the server and the browser just by sniffing network traffic, but it has other uses as well, such as ensuring that the server is who it says it is and you are who you say you are with certificates.

Fiddler2 is only able to decipher the traffic with the user's cooperation: the certificates Fiddler presents to the client are only trusted by the browser if you configure your Operating System to trust Fiddler's root certificate.

Comment: That's correct. Fiddler performs a man-in-the-middle attack, which triggers a warning in your browser unless you configure your system to trust Fiddler's certificate.

Comment: but the password is enscrypted by using some public key. how can fiddler know the private key to descript it?

Comment: Okay browser enscrypt with the public key provided by the server. Am I wrong here? So how does fiddler knows the plain password? Fiddler doesn't know the private key of the server?

Comment: My understanding is that fiddler presents it's own certificate to the browser, so the browser encrypts traffic using fiddler's public key, fiddler then decrypts it and re-encrypts it with the server's public key. Is that correct @EricLaw?

Comment: I see. And obviously browsers complain that fiddler's certificate doesn't have the authority and we got to approve that. So that means every proxy servers can steal our password then?

Comment: In the end all security depends on the end user: if they blindly accept the certificate of the man in the middle as authentic it's sort of their fault that security is broken. The attacker could also phone the user saying they are such-and-such from the IT security department and they need your password.